# How do I programmatically remove a mask that was defined in Flash Professional?

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5, mask

I realize this is a total newbie question, but it is driving me crazy...

In Flash Professional I have a movie clip, say 1000px high and 50px wide.  I have it contained within (under) a mask layer where the mask is 100px high and 50px wide.  In my program I move the movie clip vertically and as expected it is masked such that I only see 100px vertically.

My question is: how do I remove the mask from my movie clip?  When I debug inspect the movie clip in Flash Builder, its .mask property is null.  But it *is* masked...

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance,

Greg

Comment: Still haven't found an answer for this, and unfortunately I can't even post on Adobe forums, since as of yesterday (5/15/2014) Adobe Cloud Services are down worldwide.  Can't log into forums or applications.  Epic fail.  I'll post an answer here once I figure out what's going on with authortime masks.

Answer (score 1):

Greg is right. You would think that you can access the mask, that was set in Flash IDE through the mask property of DisplayObject, but you can't. Masks set in flash are always null in actionscript.

The hacky version of removing mask is that you can try to

```
displayObjectWithMaskOnIt.parent.removeChild(displayObjectWithMaskOnIt)
```

and then

```
displayObjectWithMaskOnIt.parent.addChild(displayObjectWithMaskOnIt).
```

Comment: Better solution is to remove the mask itself from the display list.

Comment: The problem is the mask isn't on the display list.  For example, I have a symbol defined with a bitmap (a sprite sheet of icons) and then it's masked by a layer that just has a rectangle.  At runtime, the instance has null mask, and the only children it contains are two Shape objects... so I don't even know how it's displaying the bitmap, unless it actually rasterized it into some kind of static Shape object at compile time.  There are obviously some nasty and mysterious optimizations occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the mask is for the parent of your MovieClip via actionscript:

```
MovieClip(movicClipInstanceName_mc.parent).mask
```

and if it is then set it to `... .mask = null;`

Usually any mask I declare in the timeline I don't mess within my AS code, since for me I think of it as a permanent condition. I would suggest setting the mask property within the AS code itself if you are wanting to programatically change it later.

```
movicClipInstanceName_mc.mask = someOtherMovieClipInstanceThatIsMyMask_mc;
```

For me doing it this way feels a lot cleaner and I feel I have more control over it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately the parent's mask is also null.  The parent is the main movie clip/stage in this case.  My masked movie clip has an instance name, and I even tried making the mask itself a movie clip.  No luck... a mask layer doesn't seem to correspond to the .mask property at all (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 0):

give an instance name to the big movie clip(say big_mc), and then

```
big_mc.mask = null;
```

Comment: Thanks.. the movie clip already had an instance name.  .mask is null for it. See my reply to ToddBFisher for more info.

Answer (score 0):

From http://forum.starling-framework.org/topic/weird-how-to-read-mask-info-from-an-swf-file

> It is very simple: the mask property is a completely different mask
>   than the timeline masks.
>
> The mask property allows you to use any object as a mask for any other
>   object (just remember to put them on the same display tree or things
>   will get nonsensical).
>
> The timeline masks designate a given range of depths as being masked
>   by a specific object.
>
> The two systems do not communicate at all, but they do the same job.
>
> You better bring out your swf parser or jsfl if you want access to the
>   timeline masks.

So timeline masks use a different mechanism, separate from the mask property.  That's why you cannot access them.  As others have mentioned, you may be able to indirectly deactivate timeline masks by removing and adding children, but short of parsing the SWF file, I don't think there's any way to detect whether the object is masked with a timeline mask in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not the answer you're looking for but this will remove the mask.
If you create a separate clip to push the mask onto it will remove the mask from the object it was masking before,

for example...

object1.mask = mask1;

then add your code to the new object
object2.mask = mask1;

because an object can only mask 1 object at a time it will now mask the new object, effectively removing the mask from the old object